# Is it possible to modify/update the plist file programmatically without replacing it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, plist

In my application 
I want to change only some content of the file.

For doing that I am fetching the plist file in dictionary.

Modifying the dictionary and then Re-Writing the whole plist file.

Is it possible to modify the plist file directly or some content of the plist file.

Comment: Depends if the plist is in text or binary format.

Comment: Would please elaborate ? thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible to modify a plist file without rewriting the whole file.  If your plist file is so big that it takes too long to rewrite the whole thing, you should look at using a SQLite database instead, and perhaps adopting Core Data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Info.plist or any resource inside your bundle (i.e.: inside MyApp.app folder) the answer is NO.
Files inside your bundle are read-only. So you cannot override them.

If you are talking about other files that could be in Documents or Cached folder then the answer is YES.

Comment: yes How ??can you provide me the code how to modify the perticular data in the plist (presented in documents directory).

Comment: You will have to read the file (using NSArray and/or NSDictionary instance methods see: http://www.iphoneexamples.com/ section Plist files ) modify what you want and then write the whole file again. You could modify martially the file but that would a much harder task (See NSFileHandle documentation)